# ARCore Unity Image Capture

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, arcore, firebase-mlkit

I am working on a poker hand recognition software with my senior design project for my B.S. in Computer Science.

My part in the project involves capturing an image of the cards on the table for our machine learning object recognition algorithm to recognize and label them.

I'm using ARCore in Unity to display overlays of the cards values onto them, and so I was wondering if it's possible/how I would go about capturing an image of the scene and update it every second or so for the machine learning algorithm? I know very little about android development (this is my first project), so I apologize if this is something obvious that's just going over my head.

TL,DR: How can I take and store pictures continuously and automatically while in an ARCore scene?

Comment: You can use `Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes()` but it offers low resolution. For a better solution you can check [this](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/221)